# How to create a local songs application in iPhone ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a music application in which I have 5 songs added to my resources folder. When I click on a button, I want all these songs to be displayed in the tableview cell of my table-view controller.

Please anybody help me to solve this problem.Actually I know to retreive songs from the documents folder of my application .But the problem is when I put songs in the document folder and if I delete  my simulator applications the music files inside the documents folder becomes null and when I run my application it shows no songs.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when you delete your app the document directory is also delete, as the document directory is in the app sandbox and can only be accessed by your app.

So you will need to ask the NSBundle for the songs:

```
NSString *songFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Song1" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Just repeat this for every song then put them in a Array so you can easily display then in the TableView.